# Newton Raphson algorithm in Python is not working; only estimates into one direction

Tags: python, r, approximation

READ FIRST: The problem was simply that the parenthesis of the absolute value should be around the actual score. The issue now is that it actually is not precise enough, it ignores the 0.000001, and more does like 0.0001 as tolerance (It stops at 54.994397921372205, when I ask it to get close to 55). I increased the tolerance to a crazy amount of 0's followed by a 1, but for instance approximating 50, it estimates 49.14!! Terrible! Why does this happen?

UPDATE: It nees to be a `float()`

I am trying to find the theta belonging to a function based on some vectors. I got this code running in R, and I was trying to literally translate this from R to Python.

I want to approximate the value for Theta when the grensscore equals 50. 
I have a starting value of theta = 0.5, and then it iterates through in R.
It only takes around 11 iterations in R to get to the point.

Sadfully, this is not working in Python, and I isolated it this much: for some reason the values can only go below the 0.5, but they cannot go above. Using a print at those places even shows that it is not running the `#a` part in the code, while the `#b` part runs. This shows that the value can never go up, and thus I can never find a value like 0.4 (because it would have to go 0.5, 0.25, 0.37.5, 0.4375 etc, but it can only go down; 0.5, 0.25, 0.125 and then stops sooner or later)

I can see it run the #b. part many times when it has to go down, but it never goes up. I switched them around as well, to see if there is an order effect but there isn't: it simply does not evaluate it to be true ever (even when I know it is)
Can anyone see what is going wrong, as this is working in R?

```
def CalcTheta(grensscore, alpha, beta):
    theta = 0.5
    estimate = [10000]   # I just set this to not error on the check
    up = 1
    down = 0

    while((math.fabs(sum(estimate)) - grensscore) > 0.00001):

        if estimate == [10000]:     # I set it like this, 
            estimate = [grensscore] # so it will skip the first run

        # a.
        if (sum(estimate) - grensscore) < 0:
            down = theta
            print(down)
            theta = (theta + up) / 2
            print(theta)

        #b.
        if (sum(estimate) - grensscore) > 0:
            print(up, down, theta)
            up = theta
            theta = (theta + down) / 2
            print(up, down, theta)

        for x in range(len(beta)):
            if x == 0:
                estimate = []

            estimate.append(math.exp(alpha[x] * (theta - beta[x]))  / (1 + math.exp(alpha[x] * (theta - beta[x]))))

    return(theta)

CalcTheta(50, data[:,1], data[:,2])
```

Comment: I am unclear as to whether you have solved this question yourself. If you have solved this question, it would be nice if you wrote an answer to your own question.

Comment: I am not sure if it is just a typo here, and the actual code is corerct, but the line with the `while` statement closes more parentheses than it opens.  I am pretty sure it will cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that

`while(math.fabs(sum(estimate)) - grensscore) > 0.00001):`

should be

`while(math.fabs(sum(estimate) - grensscore)) > 0.00001):`

With the other part, it was not a `float`, therefore it did not get really precise.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries that can do that for you. I would suggest [Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/Download) (`scipy.optimize.newton`). A recipe can be found here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576762-newton-raphson-root-finding/

Comment: I do not know the function's prime here; I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: `fprime` is optional, you only need do provide the function itself and a first estimate of the zero value.

Comment: (the actual documentation is here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html)